# Is there a best practice for allowing a user to define defaults for faceted navigation?

Tags: faceted-search, default

I'm working on an application with faceted navigation. The application will be visited often by the same group of users. A certain combination of checkboxed facets are selected by default. I would like to allow the user to change that default selection so that if they perform a certain search often they don't have to change the selection each time.

For example, assume the application allows you to see daily food prices at the local food stand:

[image: Food stand pricing application]

When you open the application, it defaults to selecting fruit (I know from research that most of my users will only use the application to purchase fruit). However, I would like to allow them to change this default. My current idea is to use a gear icon to indicate facet settings. When clicked, it shows possible defaults the application allows:

[image: Default facet selection - fruits]

If the user only ever purchases vegetables, they can change the application default by selecting the vegetable radio button:

[image: Default facet selection - vegetables]

Returning to the original question, is there a better experience to allow users to set default facet selections in a faceted navigation? Is there a best practice?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using category options in the Default Selections interaction? What if someone wants to have a default of {Apples, Bananas, Carrots}, maybe because they run a juice stand?

Comment: As @Erics pointed out those options may be conflicting. I'd suggest to simply remember the last choices. If I checked Apples & Bananas today, let them checked for me tomorow.

Answer (score 3):

I see your *set defaults* interaction is using a category system (probably because you don't want to burden that popup dialog with the full list of options, and a category system is a neat way to summarise the options).

However, what if the defaults that someone wants doesn't match any of your categories? A juice stand operator might want to have defaults of {apples, bananas, carrots, ginger}, and that crosses possibly three different categories (fruits, vegetables, herbs). Sure, they could select the "All" option, but then they'd be presented with prices for Onions, and I for one don't want my local juice stand vendor to start getting ideas.

Also, are tomatoes a fruit or a vegetable, is ginger a herb or a fruit? These are not issues you want to surprise your users with, which you inevitably will if you impose a category system on them and how you categorise things don't quite match up with how they categorise things.

I don't know of any "best practice", but one simple solution to your design challenge is to offer a simple "Set current selections as default" button.

The interaction is then a simple click, possibly with a simple confirmation dialog.

[image]